# Error when doing cURL request

Tags: php, curl

This code always returns user doesn't exist from the API:

```
$data2 = array('user'=>$vars['mcusername'],
              'pwd'=>$vars['mcpassword'],
              'group'=>$postfields['group'],
              'action'=>'Save');    

// Connect to dvb API
$configWebAddress = "http://192.168.0.12:4040/dvbapi.html?part=userconfig&";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $configWebAddress);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data2);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The string that works in a browser is this:

```
dvbapi.html?part=userconfig&user=PeterTest&pwd=obfuscated&group=1,2&disabled=0&action=Save
```

Comment: The string that works is a GET not a POST. And I hope that's not your password.

Comment: thanks for your help
but it still dosen't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access the URL in the browser, you're performing a `GET`. In your cURL attempt, you're attempting to `POST`. This is likely the issue; the script may only accept `GET`.

Try using this cURL code instead:

```
// Gather up all the values to send to the script
$data2 = array('part'   => 'userconfig',
               'user'   => $vars['mcusername'],
               'pwd'    => $vars['mcpassword'],
               'group'  => $postfields['group'],
               'action' => 'Save');  

// Generate the request URL
$configWebAddress = "http://192.168.0.12:4040/dvbapi.html?".http_build_query($data2);

// cURL the URL for a responce
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $configWebAddress);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Show the responce
var_dump($data);
```

You can use [`http_build_query()`](https://php.net/http_build_query) to turn your array into a URL-encoded string to make the `GET` request.

Comment: any special way I shoud put the url and array together ??

$data2 = array('user'=>$vars['mcusername'],
              'pwd'=>$vars['mcpassword'],
              'group'=>$postfields['group'],
              'action'=>'Save');

Comment: Sure, use `http_build_query()` on your array. See my updated answer.